# I Deleted files on internal storage but free space remains the same

Tags: internal-storage, delete

I noticed I had 623MB free in my internal storage so I connected my Android to my Laptop and navigated to the Thumbnails folder which had lot of files and was big in size. I selected all files and deleted them, it was about 300MB. Now when I read the available internal memory space, it reads 623MB...

What happened here? the files are no longer there but for some reason Android is not reflecting the increased available memory..

any clues?

Thank you!

Matias.

Comment: which phone? some services sync with the cloud so it may be back. try clearing caches and see with your file manager which files/folders are taking space.

Comment: CCleaner's app will get rid of those files properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to release the memory:

1. Connect you phone to a PC.
2. Open the memory with the File Explorer. Either "Card" or "Phone"
3. Open the file LOST.Dir
4. Erase the files in that folder.

This seems to be the recycle bin for Android.

Best!

Comment: I did a search for "LOST.Dir" nothing showed up though :(

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it may not reflect until restart. Moreover, thumbnails would be recreated once you open the images again. Perform a restart or reboot.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I restarted the phone and still the same amount of free space. I opened the Sdcard0 with an explorer within the phone and I can't see some folders, I know because the Sdcard0 shows 1..57GB used and when I enter the folder, select all folders then get properties, it's only 70MB so there are hidden files I can't see... Do I need to root my phone?

Comment: No I wouldn't recommend rooting your phone unless you know what you are doing cause that voids the warranty and can mess up your phone

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my ancient ZTE blade 2.2 device that i use for listening to audiobooks. When i deleted some files using linux file browser, the amount of free space on the device did not increase.

After some digging, i found the "removed" files inside a folder called ".Trash-1000". Deleting these freed up all the lost space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I figured how to delete files IN the internal storage.